# Problemas na instalação do Grails

Tags: windows, grails, groovy

Setei as variáveis `GRAILS_HOME` e `JAVA_HOME` que eu já utilizava para o **Griffon**, porém ao tentar acessar o **Grails** recebo o seguinte erro:

[image: ERRO]

Comment: Qual sua versão do Java? Pode ser que as versões 2.4.x precisem do Java 8, enquanto que as 2.3.x do Java 7.

Comment: O `findstr` é um comando do dos, é um problema no seu path

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não parece ser um problema do grails. Tente adicionar `C:\WINDOWS\system32` na sua variável de Ambiente `Path`

Comment: Eu instalei a versão 2.4.0 e tive esse erro mais foi tudo certo com a 2.3.9